# Counting the while result at Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, count

I have this featured listing and the code needs to count how many active featured listings the user has. I can't make the while loop work here in Wordpress. Here's code I used:

```
global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
$args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1&author='.$user_ID);
$FeaturedAdsCount = 0;

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

$featured_post = "0";

$post_price_plan_activation_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_price_plan_activation_date', true);
$post_price_plan_expiration_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_price_plan_expiration_date', true);
$todayDate = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
$expireDate = strtotime($post_price_plan_expiration_date);  

if(!empty($post_price_plan_activation_date)) {

if(($todayDate < $expireDate) or empty($post_price_plan_expiration_date)) {
            $featured_post = "1";
                    }

            }

if($featured_post == "1") { $FeaturedAdsCount++; }
endwhile;
$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;

echo $FeaturedAdsCount;
```

The output of $FeaturedAdsCount is always zero no matter if the user has active featured listing. Am I missing something here? Sorry I am still learning in PHP, self-taught actually. :) Thank you in advance! 
PS: This is the postmeta table:
[image: Postmeta table]

Comment: Check if your query result is not empty by `echo` something below the `while` call. Do the same below `if(!empty($post_price_plan_activation_date))` and post your results please.

Comment: Yes there's an echo output both below `while` call and `if(!empty($post_price_plan_activation_date))`

Comment: Try to compare the dates (`$todayDate < $expireDate`) with the unix timestamps and not in dd/mm/YY format. Otherwise e.g. 20.01.2015 will be bigger than 01.12.2015. You can just use `date()` to get the current timestamp.

Comment: There is no echo for `$expireDate` so I think this get_post_meta() is not retrieving the above table. Is there something wrong with this lines? `$post_price_plan_activation_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_price_plan_activation_date', true); $post_price_plan_expiration_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_price_plan_expiration_date_normal', true);`

Comment: Try to use `$wp_query->post->ID` instead of `$post->ID`. Also your database format is not the same. I suggest you use `var_dump($your_var)` for debugging istead of just `echo`.

Comment: Okay, I use `$wp_query->post->ID` at the get_post_meta() and this was the result `bool(false)`. Thanks by the way about the var_dump($var) advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! After hours of reading and googling, it says that when calling get_post_meta inside a loop, always use `get_the_id()` instead of `$wp_query->post->ID` or `$post->ID`. So the final get_post_meta must be like this to get a result inside a loop:

```
$post_price_plan_activation_date = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'post_price_plan_activation_date', true);
$post_price_plan_expiration_date = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'post_price_plan_expiration_date', true);
```

Thank you xphan for all the advice! :)